# SilverStripe RestfulServer basic auth fails on some servers

Tags: rest, authentication, silverstripe

I seem to have run afoul of a known bug with RESTfulServer: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-restfulserver/issues/6

I'm using SilverStripe 3.1 with RESTfulServer. On my test server, the setup functions as expected: when not logged in, a request to http://www.example.com/api/v1/ObjectName/ID pops up a basic HTML auth box, and a username and passw## Heading ##ord can be entered successfully.

The test server is running Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache2, PHP5 and MySQL5 from the repos.

On the production server, when an unauthenticated user tries to GET http://www.example.com/api/v1/ObjectName/ID the same basic HTML auth box pops up, but the login always fails.

The production server is hosted at icdsoft, running PHP5, MySQL5 and Apache2.

Things I've tried:
     - Including the credentials in the URL: http://user:pass@example.com/api/v1/ObjectName/ID
     - Removing special characters from the login name and password
     - Calling http://www.example.com/dev/build?flush=1

If anyone could shed some light on a cause or solution, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks,

Jeremy.

Comment: It seems to be a long standing bug. Maybe you could try another RESTful API module: https://github.com/colymba/silverstripe-restfulapi although authentication is via token here...